# timeout error from windows workflow

Tags: wcf, workflow, wcf-data-services, workflowservice

When i call an recevive activity in Workflow, it is showing timeout error after 1 minute.

I tried to increase the timeout by modifying the web.config as follows, but no use.

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="longTimeoutBinding" closeTimeout="10:01:00" openTimeout="10:01:00"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:10:00" >
          <security mode="None" />          
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

I have similar problem with one of WCF service also when it fectes large number of data.

Can anyone help me to find out what i am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you also set these values on the client side? It could be that the client gives up waiting for a reply.

- Could you try and reduce the timeout to 15 seconds to verify that these configs are the ones that are used.
- Could you also post the exception that you get

Comment: This has been set in both server and client side

Comment: I suggest you use the WCF tracing to find out the real cause because the timeout may be caused by it.